# How does the Monaco Editor handle onchange in React?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, monaco-editor

I'm attempting to build a code editor interface for a frontend site, and I'd like the ability to check the value and slot it into a context for another part of the application on pressing Ctrl+S. I know how to handle this with a regular textarea (event.preventDefault(), etc.), but the onChange functionality of the Monaco editor appears to simply just output the text contained within, without giving me any access to the overall event for performing checks on what buttons, etc. were pressed.

I've googled and looked around the documentation and stackoverflow, but it appears some sort of change to the docs happened recently since a lot of the doc links I've found are broken.